# How to calculate the mean of a list in a row in csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I have a data like this in an CSV file;

```
x         Y            
[2,3,4]   [3.4,2.5,3.1]
[4,5,2]   [6.2,7.5,9.7]
[2,6,9]   [4.6,2.5,2.4]
[1,3,6]   [8.9,7.5,9.2]
```

I want to calculate the mean for each list in a row

```
x                Y            
[2,3,4] < mean   [3.4,2.5,3.1] < mean
[4,5,2] < mean   [6.2,7.5,9.7] < mean
[2,6,9] < mean   [4.6,2.5,2.4] < mean
[1,3,6] < mean   [8.9,7.5,9.2] < mean
```

and output the mean value to a CSV file.

How can it achieve it using python (pandas)?

**EDIT**

After some research, I found the solution to my issue above;

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval

#csv file you want to import
filename ="xy.csv"
fields = ['X','Y'] #field names

df = pd.read_csv(filename,usecols=fields,quotechar='"', sep=',',low_memory = True)
df.X = df.X.apply(literal_eval)
df.X = df.X.apply(np.mean) #calculates mean for the list in field 'X'
print(df.X) #print result

df.Y = df.Y.apply(literal_eval)
df.Y = df.Y.apply(np.mean) #calculates mean for the list in field 'Y'
print(df.Y)
```

Comment: That's right!  You can apply `ast.literal_eval` to convert string of list back to list. It's just the same as `eval`.  `ast.literal_eval` is generally considered safer for untrusted data source.  Otherwise, for trusted source, `eval` and `ast.literal_eval` have same function.   If you use `.applymap()` instead of `.apply`, you can also do the conversion of 2 columns in one go by:  `df[fields] = df[fields].applymap(np.mean)`  (can't do the same by `.apply()`

Comment: @SeaBean thank you. your explanation makes sense. applymap is better for multiply columns calculation.

Comment: Welcome!  The main difference of `applymap()` and `apply()` is whether they apply the function element-wise or to the whole series.  In your case, you just need to calculate the mean of each list (element), applymap() is a good choice.  If you apply it to the whole series, it depends on the function in it, some functions may apply to the whole series, e.g. mean of all elements in the series.  That may not what you want then.  So, aware of the subtle difference of them.

Answer (score 2):

Via [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
# df = df.applymap(lambda x: sum(eval(x))/ len(eval(x)))
df = df.applymap(np.mean) # suggested by alex
df = df.applymap(lambda x: sum(x)/ len(x))
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
          x         Y
0  3.000000  3.000000
1  3.666667  7.800000
2  5.666667  3.166667
3  3.333333  8.533333
```

Comment: Surely `df.applymap(np.mean)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with [`np.mean()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) to map the dataframe element-wise.

```
import numpy as np

df = df.applymap(eval)     # optional step if your column is a string like a list instead of truly a list
df = df.applymap(np.mean)
```

Result:

```
print(df)


          x         Y
0  3.000000  3.000000
1  3.666667  7.800000
2  5.666667  3.166667
3  3.333333  8.533333
```